# In Ruby on Rails, how to get the request payload without metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, request

In Ruby on Rails, I am letting users upload a file. I do some stuff, then want to pass this to Amazon S3 with obj = bucket.objects[filename].write(request.body.read)

I thought I could use request.body.read or request.raw_post, however the payload has all this metadata inside it, like Content-Disposition and Content-Type.  How can I just get the part of the payload that is exactly what the user uploads?

For instance, this is request.body.read, but I just want the part starting from "ˇÿˇ‡JFIF..."

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryWc3LdZGmhHmhJeuT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ˇÿˇ‡JFIFHHˇ·...
...more data...
------WebKitFormBoundaryWc3LdZGmhHmhJeuT--
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will find the file object in the params – in your case at `params[:file]`.

The object in the `params` hash is an instance of a subclass of `IO`. Depending on the size of the uploaded file it may be a `StringIO` or an instance of `File` (a temporary file).

In both cases, the object will have an `original_filename` attribute containing the name of the file that it had on the user's computer and a `content_type` attribute containing the MIME type of the uploaded file.

To just read the file content just call `read`.

```
uploaded_file = params[:file]

uploaded_file.original_filename 
#=> test.jpg

uploaded_file.read 
#=> file content ("ˇÿˇ‡JFIFHHˇ...")
```

Read more about [uploading files in the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files).